# how to make a pop up button that includes both images and contents in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
here my functions.php
function avail_rooms(){

$output .= '<div class="main-room-image">';
$output .= '<div class="room-image"><img src="'.home_url ('/').'images/deluxe-room.jpg" alt="Deluxe Room" title="Deluxe Room" />';
$output .= '<div class="room-txt"><a href="'.get_permalink(177).'">Deluxe Room</a></div></div>';

$output .= '<div class="room-image"><img src="'.home_url ('/').'images/twin-deluxe-room.jpg" alt="Twin Deluxe Room" title="Twin Deluxe Room" />';
$output .= '<div class="room-txt"><a href="'.get_permalink(192).'">Twin Deluxe Room</a></div></div>';

$output .= '<div style="display:none;">';
$output .= '<div claas="room-image"><img src="'.home_url ('/').'images/sample-image.jpg" alt="" title="" />';
$output .= '<div class="room-txt">Sample</div></div>';
$output .= '</div>';

$output .= '</div>';


return $output;
}
add_shortcode('avail_rooms','avail_rooms');
```

advance many thanks for idea and shared information.. iwant to make a pop-up box that has image and content with it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) in `jQuery` which toggles two or more elements with slide effect

Sample Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2beF/1/

Check this too : http://jsfiddle.net/Y2beF/2/

Comment: hi, can i have some example here?

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the $output into a a link (a href) to generate a popup or javascript to drive/fire up a light box (i.e [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)).

Comment: hi., can i have some example here?